# kill node server after tests have run gitlab

Tags: javascript, node.js, gitlab-ci

I am trying to spin up a node server on my gitlab server. I have set up my `gitlab-ci.yml` file and it all seems to work. However, I want to kill the node server after the tests have finished running.

The relevant section of my `gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like this:

```
unit_tests:
  stage: test
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: clone
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run websocket-server
    - npm test
  after_script:
      - //what should go here to kill the node server after the tests have run?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pkill` for that.

A simple usage method could be something like this:

```
after_script:
  - pkill node
```

Read `pkill(1)`'s manual for more info:
https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill